# TTF font to METAFONT natural conversion

Tags: fonts

Is there a way to convert TTF font to METAFONT so even Plain TeX can use it? (I do not wish to use external packages to accomplish this goal either)

Comment: Plain is not limited to using metafont, as far as I know. pdfTeX can use type1 and truetype; XeTeX/LuaTeX can use system fonts, although I'm not sure whether there's a mechanism for loading them with plain. TeX itself can use type1, as far as I know.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `natural` conversion. I doubt there is any non-manual way of doing it either naturally or unnaturally. It is also hard to see how there could be.

Comment: The `plain` format is limited in font selection by the underlying engine.  Could it hence be, that you meant Knuth TeX instead of Plain TeX?  But then, who uses Knuth TeX these days?

Comment: @HenriMenke -- the computer modern fonts are available as type 1, and have been for many years.  any font with a `tfm` file can be used by knuth tex.  a metafont origin is not required.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, it is required, [at least for arXiv](https://arxiv.org/help/faq/mistakes#fonts)

Comment: @mapto -- The arXiv instructions specify that metafont fonts are required only for *unusual/uncommon* fonts.  There's no way such a source could be required for a Times font, for example -- it doesn't exist.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, no contradiction here. Maybe I should have made it explicit that one would need font sources only if working with fonts that are not widely distributed.